# Conversion of oxalic acid to malonic acid

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis

[image: Oxalic acid to malonic acid]

The reagents I have used here are $\ce{LiAlH_4}$ which reduces the carboxylic groups into alcohol.Used $\ce{HIO_4}$ which breaks up the molecule into methanal. Then  I applied Grignard reagent which consisted ethyl for the alkyl part.Then I tried to oxide the terminal carbon into $\ce{COOH}$  but could not find a suitable reagent.

What is a better approach and a method to solve this question.

Comment: Arndt–Eistert, maybe?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arndt%E2%80%93Eistert_reaction

Comment: I would be wary of using a multistep reaction to try to homologate only *one* carboxylic acid group of oxalic acid... maybe forming a monoester first would work.

Comment: I would fully reduce to the diol and convert to the epoxide. Then, form the halohydrin and oxidize to $\alpha$-chloro acetic acid. Should be pretty straightforward after that. Going through the halohydrin would allow you to desymmetrize the starting material.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Arndt-Eistert procedure suggested above seems very applicable to this problem. To use it we need ethyl oxalyl chloride. This can be prepared in 2 steps from oxalic acid by first esterification to form diethyl oxalate  [procedure here](https://thosci.com/synthesis-of-diethyl-oxalate/) then reaction with PCl5 to form ethyl oxalyl chloride [procedure here](http://www.prepchem.com/synthesis-ethyl-chlorooxoacetate/). This can undergo the Arndt-Eistert [mechanism here](https://chemguide.quora.com/Arndt-Eistert-Reaction) with excess diazomethane then either irradiation or treatment with silver oxide to give monoethyl malonate. Simple base hydrolysis then gives the required.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you want oxalic acid as the only source of carbon

$\ce{(COOH)2 ->[\Delta, -CO2] CO ->[Cl2] COCl2  }$

$\ce{(COOH)2 ->[LiAlH4; H3O+] (CH2OH)2 ->[H3O+,\Delta] CH3CHO }$

$\ce{CH3CHO ->[B:-] CHO-CH2- ->[COCl2, huge excess; H3O+] CHO-CH2-COOH ->[Ag2O] CH2(COOH)2   }$

The key here is to split target molecule into $\ce{C1}$ and $\ce{C2}$ fragments and then find a way to find a way to make enolizable $\ce{C2}$ compound from oxalic acid. There is more then one way to obtain phosgene, one I pointed here wouldn't work in a lab. AFAIK phosgene can be obtained by thermal decomposition of oxalyl chloride, but I couldn't find trustworthy looking reference with quick googling.

rearrangement of ethylene glycol might required rather harsh conditions.

.....
That one was fun.

Comment: By Arndt–Eistert any luck?

Comment: @starunique2016 The common restriction in this type of problems is either to not use outer sources of carbon or not use other organic compounds. Besides, Arnds-Eistert isn't very common. For this reasons I do not consider Arnds-Eistert a valid step for this problem unless OP states otherwise  by quoting exact wording of the problem.

Comment: If i want by Arndt-Eistert only?

Comment: That ethylene glycol one i have my doubts

Comment: @user57048 Rearrangement or synthesis ? Rearrangement is referenced in literature, it is a variant of  pinacol–pinacolone rearrangement.

Comment: I specifically wanted Arndt-Eistert  so i didnt accept this answer,but +1 anyways